how to use the keyword auto in c++
I got some code as below which is about the usage of auto that the keyword should be involved in c++11. But I can't understand how the below code works. Could you please help give some clue? Thanks!
bool is = true;
auto exp = [is](const char * ch) -> bool {
if (!ch)
    return false;
if(*ch == 'a')
    return true;
};

As I understand, exp is assigned a code block which seems to be a function call, and ch is the parameter of the function. When using exp, it should be something like exp('x');.
But I can't understand the other part of the expression.
[is](const char * ch) -> bool


auto, in this case, works out the type of exp from the type of initialiser, which is a lambda.  Lambdas are special in that their type is unspecified and unique (no two lambdas have the same type) but, that aside, auto works as it would for any other initialiser  (since the implementation [compiler] knows what type it has deemed that this lambda has).   Side note:  exp is a rather poor choice of name for a variable, since exp is the name of a function in the standard library (exp() in <math.h>), so there is a potential name clash.

learncpp.com 10.8 — Type deduction for objects using the auto keyword and Lambda expression

The code is in danger of invoking undefined behaviour. It's not OK to write a function that says it's going to return a value (a bool in this case) and then not do so.

There's also an unused capture [is]. Either the code is rubbish, or you quoted it incorrectly.

If ch is not null, and *ch does not point to an a, it doesn't return anything and is undefined behavior (which is bad).

"exp is assigned a code block"  No.  exp is assigned a lambda.  "and ch is the parameter of the function"  It's not a function, it's a lambda.
